# RDMA Fast Memory Registration (FMR)

Tags: infiniband, rdma, mellanox, ofed

I'm developing a system that uses RDMA extensively (on Mellanox hardware) and would like to be able to register memory regions more efficiently/faster.

I have taken a look into Fast Memory Registration and I have a few questions:

1. **Is FMR going away?** From here [1] it seems it might get removed/replaced soon.
2. Is there any **user-space code** out there that makes use of this feature? There are only a few threads online discussing this and mostly in the context of kernel modules.

Any useful pointers would be greatly appreciated.

[1] https://jira.hpdd.intel.com/browse/LU-5783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that kernel developers would like to get FMR removed. See for example this [future of FMR](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-rdma/msg30695.html) thread on linux-rdma.

FMR (and FRWR) are only used in the kernel. User-space isn't trusted to use these operations as they allow access to the physical address space and could break process isolation.

Comment: Yes, but FMR memory can be registered from user-space [1]. If you know of any public code that uses this feature I would like to take a look.
[1] http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/rdma/ib_verbs.h?v=3.2#L734

Comment: This is fast registration, not FMR. Take a look at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/infiniband/core/uverbs_cmd.c?v=4.8#L2493, it is not possible to post a fast registration work request from userspace.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was not aware of that.

Comment: Yes , FMR is removed.and all kernel code containing that.https://lore.kernel.org/linux-rdma/12-v3-f58e6669d5d3+2cf-fmr_removal_jgg@mellanox.com/